# Discord Music Bot Youtube Playlists not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, youtube-api

Hello I am trying to solve a problem with a Discord Music Bot, it works fine with Spotify songs and playlists, but Youtube playlists no (although songs it does work). I can add song by song to the queue but not a list.

This is the error:

> music_message 476:TypeError: arr is not iterable

in this part of the code:

```
 if (isYoutube(qry) && isYoutubePlaylist(qry)) {
     try {
         const arr = await youtube_tracks_from_playlist(qry);
         for (let item of arr)
             addToQueue(item, mapKey)
         message.react(EMOJI_GREEN_CIRCLE)
     } catch (e) {
         console.log('music_message 476:' + e)
         message.channel.send('Failed to process playlist: ' + qry);
     }
 }
```

But due to the fact that the error is that it cannot be iterated I guess the error comes from before and the format of the object. So here is the function:

```
async function youtube_tracks_from_playlist(url, isretry=false) {
    const data = await ytlist(url, 'url');
    console.log("Type of youtube data: " + typeof data)
    console.log("Data: " + data)
    if (data && 'data' in data && 'playlist' in data.data && data.data.playlist && data.data.playlist.length) {
        return data.data.playlist
    } else {
        if (!isretry) {
            console.log('retrying yt playlist processing')
            return await youtube_tracks_from_playlist(url, true);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in case it helps here are the outputs of the console to types of data and ytlist def:

```
const ytlist = require('youtube-playlist');
```

> Type of youtube data: object
>
> Data: [object Object]
>
> Type of arr: object
>
> arr: null

So, I have no clue if that [object Object] is the common thing I am supposed to get, or what is the problem?

Comment: `arr` is `null`, `youtube_tracks_from_playlist` returns `null` in exactly one condition. So... What's the actual problem?

Comment: the problem is in Data, which should have a data.playlist parameter and apparently it doesn't right? But I dont really know, that is why I am asking